# Insufficient funds in main account (etherbase)main account for gas

Tags: gas

I'm using Ethereum/Mist 087.

I have 2000 eth in the main account. Trying to send 1800 from the main account to another ether account and Coinbase account. Each time we get the message:

> Insufficient funds in main account (etherbase) to pay for gas

I would have thought that 200 ether would be enough gas.

We are using the Ethereum wallet to "Send" and get that error. I have search the web and only see the code that has that error. Nothing on why.

Comment: check https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2173 open an issue in the mist hub.